# Better way to start next webrequest

Tags: vb.net

I am using HTTPWEBREQUEST and responses to go through a listbox and post to a form, then return and parse results. When the parsing is done, I want the index in the listbox to increase and the webrequest to be called over again.

Currently, my code for returning data is:

```
Dim postreqreader2 As New StreamReader(postresponse2.GetResponseStream())
Dim thepage2 As String = postreqreader2.ReadToEnd
richTextBox2.Text = thepage2
```

Then in my RichTextBox2TextChanged Event, I am parsing. At the end of the parse, I increase the list index and recall the webrequest function but it is not working. (the webrequest). Because the index is changing properly. If i press button1 again, it will grab the next data from listbox. What could be causing this? Is there a better way to know when the first request is done/finished/closed then to call the next request? Is using the textchanged event a good way to even know when to parse?

Comment: you need to show a bit more code, where do you change the index, how do you build your request?